# Decrease width of grid column when is decreasing window width

Tags: wpf, grid

I would like have a way how "hide" grid columns  when a user decreases width of window.

For example I have simple grid 4 columns and rows.

Code is very simple:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="172" Width="775">
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,5,20,5" FontSize="25">0.0</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,5,20,5" FontSize="25">0.1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,5,20,5" FontSize="25">1.0</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,5,20,5" FontSize="25">1.1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,5,20,5" FontSize="25">2.0</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,5,20,5" FontSize="25">2.1</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" Margin="20,5,20,5" FontSize="25">3.0</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,5,20,5" FontSize="25">3.1</TextBlock>
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

[image]

Now user start decreasing window width.

I would like first "hide" column number 3 then 2 then 1 and as last column number 0.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I thinking about use  converter on columns width and bind width of window.
In converter I can calculate column width.

I don’t that this is suitable way. Have you any idea? Thank

Comment: @user572844: Do you want the columns to resize at all when you change the width of the Window or do you want them to have fixed width?

Comment: Meleak I edited my question. I try achieve this behavior. If user reduce window width, first column which is hided is number 3, than col 2, than column 1 and col 0 can have MinWidth fixed. Sory for my english, I am 16 years Poland and have big problem describe what I need. Do you undestand me yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oki, behavior what I need it possible achieve with this code:

```
<ColumnDefinition       Width="{Binding ElementName=ChatWindow, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Converter={StaticResource columnsWidthConverter}, 
ConverterParameter=Col0}"/>

<ColumnDefinition       Width="{Binding ElementName=ChatWindow, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Converter={StaticResource columnsWidthConverter}, 
ConverterParameter=Col1}"/>

<ColumnDefinition       Width="{Binding ElementName=ChatWindow, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Converter={StaticResource columnsWidthConverter}, 
ConverterParameter=Col2}"/>

<ColumnDefinition       Width="{Binding ElementName=ChatWindow, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Converter={StaticResource columnsWidthConverter}, 
ConverterParameter=Col3}"/>

<ColumnDefinition       Width="{Binding ElementName=ChatWindow, Path=Width, Mode=OneWay, 
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
Converter={StaticResource columnsWidthConverter}, 
ConverterParameter=Col4}"/>
```

Convertor on columns width:

```
public class ColumnsWidthConverter : IValueConverter
{

    Dictionary<string, int> _columnToMinimumRequiredWidthMapping = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        { "col0", 0 },
        { "col1", 270 },
        { "col2", 520 },
        { "col3", 770 },
        { "col4", 1020 }
    };

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string colName = parameter.ToString();
        int windowWidth = System.Convert.ToInt32(value.ToString());
        const int colWidth = 180;

        if (_columnToMinimumRequiredWidthMapping.ContainsKey(colName))
        {
            return windowWidth >= _columnToMinimumRequiredWidthMapping[colName] ? colWidth : 0;
        }

        return colWidth;
    }


    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<Grid ShowGridLines="True" MinWidth="775">
```

Comment: But with this I achive that first column stay visible, but I need erliest "hide" column 3 number than 2 than 1 a than 0.

Comment: As you reduce the width of the window, column 3 is hidden, then column 2 and then column 1.  Isn't that what you wanted?  Is the problem that partial columns are shown when reducing the window width?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the columns spaced as they are, you could add a horizontal scrollbar so that when the screen is resized the user can still see the other columns:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid Width="400" ...>
            ...
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```